# gulp rename consider .min.js as the extension

Tags: gulp, gulp-rename

In a gulp task, I want to include a javascript file and inserting version within the file name.

Basically, in my task, I want to copy :

- `./node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js` to `./dist/js/bootstrap.3.3.7.js`
- `./node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js` to `./dist/js/bootstrap.3.3.7.min.js`

I defined this task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var bsInfo = require('./node_modules/bootstrap-sass/package.json');

...

gulp.task('assets:js', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js', './node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js'])
        .pipe(rename(function (path) { path.basename += "." + bsInfo.version; }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});
```

However, the generated file names are:

- bootstrap.3.3.7.js (correct)
- bootstrap.min.3.3.7.js (incorrect, min is before the version number).

How can I write my task to output the correct file name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your rename pipe:

```
.pipe(rename(function (file) {

      if (file.basename.endsWith(".min")) {
        file.basename = file.basename.slice(0, -4) + "." + bsInfo.version + ".min";
      }
      else {
        file.basename += "." + bsInfo.version;
      }
   }))
```